# How to set the justification for all the standard paragraphs in a LyX document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, paragraphs

This must be trivial.  I am new to LyX but I have read most of the 183 page User Guide and not found the answer.  When I change the justification setting (to remove right justify) it only does it for the current paragraph.  Document-Settings-Textlayout offers very limited ability to make changes.

If I open the Customization Guide, the heading says "Features for the Advanced User".  Surely something as trivial as turning off justification does not require advanced user customization.  It looks like local layout may be the answer.  But the customization guide says enter a format tag and searching the guide for "format tag" yields no results.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: By removing the "right justify", what are you interested in? A ragged-right display for the paragraph(s)?

Comment: You could just add `\raggedleft` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed (though I wanted ragged right).  I guess by the time you are an expert LyX user, you get really keen on the appearance of a document.  However, I am more concerned that it should be easy to read and right justified text is more difficult to read.

Comment: Anyway help out a poor noob for a moment.  I am puzzled at how difficult it was to find out that simple trick.  Nowhere in the user guide that I can see either refers to the raggedright command, or explains the preamble.  The meagre reference to it seems to assume you are a Latex expert.  So, as I go on, is that what I must expect - to be required to have expert Latex knowledge at every stage?  That would be odd as I installed LyX for the sole reason that it would be quicker to learn than Latex.

Comment: @hfffoman I actually always recommend LyX users learn LaTeX before using LyX. Many do not share my opinion though. In any case, `\raggedleft` is not an expert LaTeX command. You could have found that out by googling for a LaTeX solution and then you can convert it to a LyX solution as Werner pointed out. In any case, I love and use LyX everyday, but it is a preference thing. If the only reason you're using it is to avoid LaTeX at all costs, then you will be frustrated. It's nearly impossible to avoid using LaTeX when using LyX, and in my opinion that's not a bad thing. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you are an expert it may seem obvious but I spent about 2 hours trying to find that solution including looking on google.  I don't know how I was supposed to know that a simple instruction requires googling under Latex when the first sentence of the tutorial says "you will not need to learn LaTeX to use LyX" and the first thing I saw after installing was: Use the Lyx documentation, it's excellent. I am happy to learn Latex but I have a lot of work to do and thought lyx would save time as it was quicker to learn.  Was I being naive?

Comment: @Werner Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @hfffoman: Note that users generally aren't notified about comments unless you write `@<username>` as I did above.  scottkosty was therefore likely not notified of your last comment, which could explain why he hasn't responded.

Answer (score 1):

Open up `stdclass.inc` and find the `Standard` style:

```
Style Standard
    Category              MainText
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Paragraph
    LatexName             dummy
    ParIndent             MM
    ParSkip               0.4
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
    LabelType             No_Label
    # FIXME This ought to be set dynamically.
    HTMLStyle
        div.standard {
            margin-bottom: 2ex;
        }
    EndHTMLStyle
End
```

The `Align` property designates the default justification under the `Standard` style. In the above case, the default is `Block`. Available alignments are given under `AlignPossible`

- `Block` = Justified (or left- and right-aligned);
- `Left` = `\raggedright`
- `Right` = `\raggedleft`
- `Center` = `\centering`

Change `Align` to `Left` and insert it as a Local Layout under Document > Settings... to obtain a `\raggedright` output:

[image]

Of course, it would also be possible to define your own, new paragraph style.

---

An easy LaTeX-type way of achieving this is by issuing `\raggedright` in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the look of the LyX input to ragged right, but still want to keep the justification of the pdf/ps output, then you can go to Document/Text Layout and unclick "Use justification in LyX work area".