# Set alignment for paragraphs in LyX (only for the editor)

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I am new to LyX. The default setting for the alignment for standard paragraph is 'Justified'. This gives me some inconvenience with long footnotes. For example,

[image]

[image]

So, I change the alignment setting to 'Left'. But this makes the paragraph left aligned both in the LyX editor and in the resulting pdf file after typesetting. I am wondering if there is a way to change the alignment **merely** in the LyX editor without changing the alignment of the pdf file?

I would also appreciate if people have other solutions to my problem here.

P.S. = I noticed some discussion here: [How to set the justification for all the standard paragraphs in a LyX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193099/how-to-set-the-justification-for-all-the-standard-paragraphs-in-a-lyx-document). But the solutions seem to make adjustments to both LyX editor and the resultant pdf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Document > Settings > Text Layout and uncheck "Use justification in LyX work area".